# Planetside 2 UI isn't loading strings (names) properly - corrupt file not being fixed (Steam)

Tags: steam, planetside-2

When I load up the game, I see ##UI.Play, ##UI.Settings, ##UI.Exit, etc in place of the correct Play, Settings, and Exit.

In game, I get "Error" for weapon names or "weaponID.string not found" etc which makes playing the game for the first time rather difficult.

I installed through Steam and have re-verified the content several times and it has found corrupt files each time.

It now finds only 1 corrupt file but doesn't say what it is.

Is there somehow I can find the file in question and delete it myself? I'd prefer not having to re-download the whole game at about 10GB.

Comment: I think you can start (and verify) the game through its own launcher even if you have the Steam version. Not sure where it's located though and if it doesn't cause bugs, not using Steam.

Comment: @MartinSojka - I tried that to no avail. It might work for others in a similar situation though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't want to delete/change the old answer since it still might be useful for other people, even if it wasn't the correct answer in this case. I flagged it as community wiki.

I googled for the problem and found a solution. You have to change the language in the launcher to anything else (possibly accepting the EULA again by clicking the green button) and then change the language back.

[image]

Source:

Comment: Ah, this sounds promising; will report back.

Answer (score 3):

Verify the game files through the launcher, not through Steam.

Verifying through Steam corrupts the whole installation and deletes a lot of files, which is a problem the developers are working on together with Valve.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Still has the same problem even after validating/rebooting/updating/deleting&re-downloading.

Answer (score 1):

If changing languages﻿ doesn't work, try this:
Run the PlanetSide 2 Launchpad but do not press play
Click the Advanced Tools icon (looks like a wrench in a hexagon)
Click Open Game Directory
In Windows Explorer, open the Locale folder
Copy the en_us_data.dat and the en_us_data.dir files to a temporary location
Rename your copied files to: en_gb_data.dat and en_gb_data.dir
Place these new files into the Locale folder and close Windows Explorer